# Составной ключ с авноикрементом

Tags: sql-server

Приветствую всех. Проблема вот какая.
Есть таблица, для примера, с тремя полями. Два из которых образуют первичный ключ:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Hash] NVARCHAR(32),
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Data] NTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Hash], [Id])
)
```

При таком объявлении таблицы, значение Id инкрементируется независимо от значения `Hash`, то есть фактически `Hash` уже и не нужен.
Но я хочу, что бы для каждого `Hash Id` был независимый, то есть что бы его значения повторялись для разных `hash`. Есть способ это сделать?
Про вариант с триггером знаю, но интересует, возможно ли провернуть такой трюк без дополнительных сложностей.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, IDENTITY увеличивается всегда при следующей вставке, без возможности добавить доп. условие.